# How to create a user (work account) with specified directory role in Azure Active Directory Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to find out a way to create a User (work account) with specified DirectoryRole in Azure Active Directory Graph API using one Azure AD Graph API call.

I can make two separate calls (one to create the user and one to assign the DirectoryRole) but is it possible to include the role in the `POST` user payload and assign the role in the same call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently as of today, the Azure AD Graph REST Api is not able to create a user with a non-default directory role in one call

So we should make 2 separate calls To create a user and a second call to make the user a member of the Directory Role.

I didn't find any documentation around this, but had a chat with someone from AD team and he informed me of this.

Comment: How do we create new roles into our custom roles via graph api ?

Comment: @JenishZinzuvadiya You can Activate directory roles using existing role templates: POST  https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryRoles?api-version take a look at this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/directoryroles-operations