# How to create a user (work account) with specified directory role in Azure AD Graph API

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory

[How to create a user (work account) with specified directory role in Azure Active Directory Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999305/how-to-create-a-user-work-account-with-specified-directory-role-in-azure-activ/46091578#46091578)

Did you find any refrence for so we should make 2 separate calls to create an user and a second call to add the user as a member of the Directory Role. Or its not possible at the moment and AD team researching on the query.

I read your post Sadiqh

There is nothing clear so i need to ask you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not support to create a user and assign the role within the same request. Because when we need to provide the object id of users who we want to assign the role, however this is not supported by [Azure AD batch request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-batch-processing).

And AFAIK, this is also not supported by the [Microsoft Graph batch request](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching). Microsoft is working on Microsoft Graph at present, if you have any idea or feedback, you can submit it from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).